# Please help me with a (simple?) "solve for x" problem.

Tags: factoring, quadratic-forms, quadratics

I'm preparing for the GRE and was working through an old textbook (chapter on quadratic equations "completing the square," if that helps) and got stumped on $\displaystyle x^2 +{\frac{5x}{a}} + 6x^2 = 10$.  Kindly tell me how the author came up with $\displaystyle x= -5 \pm {\frac{\sqrt{305}}{14a}}$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and the author is wrong. What happened is that he set up the quadratic formula ok. Then at the end he multiplied top and bottom by $a$. He multiplied the $25/a^2$ with $a^2$ which is right but forgot to do that with the $280$ So instead of $280a^2$ he added $25+280=305$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\displaystyle 7x^2 + \frac{5}{a}x - 10 = 0$. Use quadratic formula to finish.

Comment: Please use latex.

Comment: @2012ssohn Please do not format this user's posts! You are enabling their laziness by doing so.

Comment: @amWhy Whether it enables laziness or not, I don't think it's right to roll back an edit purposefully to make the post look worse.

Comment: @T.Bongers I did not roll-back to make the post look worse. I rolled back to return the answer to the answerer's intended state. If the post looked worse, blame it on the answerer. The roll-back simply returned the post to its original state. I don't think it's right to roll-back to "beautify" the answerer's post.

Comment: @amWhy Fair enough, and I was careless with my wording when suggesting you did it to make it worse. However, since helping users out with MathJax is quite routine, I don't consider it right to roll back the MathJax inserted by another user; editing shouldn't make the post worse.

Answer (score 0):

The author has used the quadratic formula to get the solution.

See the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation